# How to wait asyncio stream read() until current coroutine finished reading

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm using this example provided in [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html) on asyncio streams, to write data and read from a socket.

I am consuming `rabbitmq` and sending the messages through the socket and waiting for a response. I've setup the `reader` and `writer` in `__init__()` :

```py
    self.reader, self.writer = await asyncio.open_connection(self.host, self.port, loop=self.loop)
```

and in consuming messages, I just send the message to the socket and read the response, then publish the response to another queue (after some processing):

```py
    async def process_airtime(self, message: aio_pika.IncomingMessage):
        async with message.process():
            logger.info('Send: %r' % message.body)
            self.writer.write(message.body)

            data = await self.reader.read(4096)
            logger.info('Received: %r' % data)

            await self.publish(data) # publishing to some other queue
```

The problem is when i try to consume like say 10 messages, all other messges raise this error, although the last message successfully gets a response..

```
RuntimeError: read() called while another coroutine is already waiting for incoming data
```

This is the response i get(i've truncated some response..):

```
2022-02-05 10:59:17,123 INFO [__main__:130] request_consumer [*] waiting for messages...
Send: b'\x00\x00\x00"000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
Send: b'\x00\x00\x00"000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
Send: b'\x00\x00\x00"000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'

...


2022-02-05 10:59:17,194 ERROR [asyncio:1707] base_events Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-53' coro=<consumer() done, defined at /home/steven/workspace/python/onfon/cheka/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aio_pika/queue.py:25> exception=RuntimeError('read() called while another coroutine is already waiting for incoming data')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/steven/workspace/python/onfon/cheka/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aio_pika/queue.py", line 27, in consumer
    return await create_task(callback, message, loop=loop)
  File "request_consumer.py", line 122, in process_airtime
    data = await self.reader.read(4096)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/streams.py", line 684, in read
    await self._wait_for_data('read')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/streams.py", line 503, in _wait_for_data
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: read() called while another coroutine is already waiting for incoming data
2022-02-05 10:59:17,194 ERROR [asyncio:1707] base_events Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-54' coro=<consumer() done, defined at /home/steven/workspace/python/onfon/cheka/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aio_pika/queue.py:25> exception=RuntimeError('read() called while another coroutine is already waiting for incoming data')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/steven/workspace/python/onfon/cheka/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aio_pika/queue.py", line 27, in consumer
    return await create_task(callback, message, loop=loop)
  File "request_consumer.py", line 122, in process_airtime
    data = await self.reader.read(4096)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/streams.py", line 684, in read
    await self._wait_for_data('read')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/streams.py", line 503, in _wait_for_data
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: read() called while another coroutine is already waiting for incoming data
Received: b'\xf2>D\x95\n\xe0\x80 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
```

My question is, what should i, probably, do to make read() be called again only after a current coroutine `read`ing has finished. Will that affect performance or is there some way i can read on, say, different threads?

I will appreciate if someone points me the right direction.
I use python3.8 on linux

Comment: I think this error is related to the internal structure of sockets that must use the `reader` behind scenes. A socket that is reading/receiving without a **timeout** is going to be busy until some data arrives to it, and in that way blocked for future reading operations. The `asyncio` module gives you the ability to call the function `reader.read` concurrently but using the same socket that is already blocked.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is to only `read()` from one task.

It sounds like you are using a callback to consume RMQ messages. If so, then aio_pika will consume messages asynchronously (ie. concurrently) if it has a multiple messages. That is, it will create a new task for each callback/message and leave it to its own devices.

Given that you have a read() whilst processing a message, that doesn't really make sense for your read calls. How will you know which read is for which message. You need to find some way to sync your
reads to each message. There are a few ways you can do this:

- Put a lock around calls to `read()`
- Creating a separate task that is solely responsible for calling `read()`, it
  puts the results onto a queue, from which any task can read. asyncio
  queues are task safe (unlike `read()`).
- Or perhaps most simply, by using the queue as an iterator (and
  not spawning a new task to handle the message).

I am assuming you current code looks something a bit like:

```py
async def init_rmq_consumer():
    # connect to RMQ and create a queue
    ...
    queue = ...

    # start consuming messages off of the queue
    await queue.consume(process_airtime)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(init_rmq_consumer())
    loop.run_forever()
```

Using the queue as an iterator might look something like:

```py
async def main():
    # connect to RMQ and create a queue
    ...
    queue = ...

    # start consuming messages off of the queue *serially*
    async with queue.iterator() as queue_iter:
         async for message in queue_iter:
              # we will not fetch a new message from the queue until we are
              # finished with this one.
              await process_airtime(message)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: i tried this, this morning, and yeah i get all responses, but it is so slow, just like using normal sockets, i dont get the power of asyncio, responses take up to 500 ms to arrive. What i dont get is why asyncio could write all messages asynchronously, but fail to read asynchronously.